# How to find in AWS Cost Management/ Cost Explorer the costs by region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cost-explorer

How to find in AWS Cost Management/ Cost Explorer the costs by region?
Or other way?
I would like to see something like the cost "by Services" but "by Region".
My goal is to find the regions where resources are deployed. I want to do something like an audit for an AWS account migration to another AWS account.
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Costs by region

1. Go to the *AWS Cost Management Console* > *Cost Explorer*
2. Set the `Date range` and `Granularity` to whatever time frame and resolution you're interested in
3. Set `Group by` to "`Region`"
4. Select the left most graph view ("`Bar graph`") to have all regions separately side by side

[image]

> Hover over bars to see the specific numbers

### Costs by service by region

Unfortunately this is not feasible with just a single query (via the UI). What you can do however, is to take all relevant regions that you found in "Costs by region" above, and inspect them separately:

1. Set `Group by` to "`Service`"
2. Set `Region` (under filters) to the region that you want to inspect

[image]

If you want to automate this, you can do it by [using the Cost Explorer API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-api.html). But [this will cost you something](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-what-is.html) - unlike the queries via the user interface, which are free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

***Region*** is one of the dimensions by which costs can be grouped in the Cost Explorer console:

[image: AWS Cost Explorer Dimension selection]

Select it to view your costs broken down by region.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to `AWS Cost Management` -> `Cost Explorer`  on the right side you can see `Report parameters`
There, you can choose `Group by` and set it to `Region`. Unfortunately, this only gives you per region grouping, not per service per region, unless you apply additional filters to choose only specific services.

Now, if you want to see resources per region, you can also use `AWS Resource Explorer` which can index all your resources and you can export them to CSV